# Remove month navigation buttons in uib-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

how to disable/remove the month/year navigation button on the Angular uib-datepicker (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker)

[image]

We want to remove the ability for users to click on the "Month/Year" text in between the navigation arrows and can't figure it out

Comment: i belive, if you change the template, for some wich not contauins header with mont, will?template-url (Default: uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can hide it with CSS:

```
.uib-datepicker thead
{
    display:none;
}
 /* fix weeks padding if showing weeks */
.text-center.h6.ng-scope {
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access the template html itself and remove/disable the `input` associated with that button

[The template on github can be found here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepicker/day.html)

You will have to modify line 5

```
 <th colspan="{{::5 + showWeeks}}"><button id="{{::uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>
```

This is only for day mode, you can do the same for month and year modes if necessity will come